# clone and selectbox onchange change value of input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, clone

i have problem with clone and change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addBarang();
});

function addBarang() {
  var new_barang = $(".hidden_input").find(".barang_in").clone().addClass("barang_in_clone");
  $(".target_clone:last").append(new_barang);
  //        $(".barang_in_clone:has(select)").addClass("select2");
}

$('body').on('click', '.btn_kurangi_barang', function() {
  $(this).closest('.barang_in_clone').remove();
});

function showModel(id){
if(id === ''){
$("input[name=show]").val("");
}else if(id === "1"){
$("input[name=show]").val("foo");
}else if(id === "2"){
$("input[name=show]").val("bar");
}else{
$("input[name=show]").val("too");
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="hidden_input" style="display: none">
    <div class="barang_in">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Kode Hanca</label>
      <select onchange='showModel(this.value)' name="id_vendor_detail" class="form-control" required="">
        <option value="">- PILIH -</option>
        <option value="1">- Orange -</option>
        <option value="2">- Pink -</option>
        <option value="3">- Red -</option>

      </select>
      <button onclick="addBarang()" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="tambah vendor" class="btn btn-info btn-flat btn-xs pull-left btn_tambah_vendor"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add</button>
      <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="kurangi barang" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-xs pull-right btn_kurangi_barang"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove</button>
      <input type='text' name='show'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='target_clone'>
  </div>

</body>
```

when i clone data, its show many selectbox. and when i select the selectbox, i want to change `<input type='text' name='show'>` by value from `if else` . how can i do ?

> **dummy text** : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
>   elit. Phasellus at lectus orci. Quisque maximus hendrerit consequat.
>   Donec blandit facilisis est. Integer ac massa vitae ante vulputate
>   sagittis nec at nisl. Cras sit amet sem nec metus sodales eleifend a
>   ac nulla. Duis porta nisl in erat aliquet hendrerit. Integer mollis
>   non odio et pellentesque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit. Suspendisse cursus fringilla sem, facilisis malesuada
>   orci varius in. Nullam tristique nisi sed sem mattis, a finibus magna
>   mollis. Fusce erat sem, semper ac vulputate sit amet, imperdiet
>   sagittis ex

Comment: please run the snippet

Comment: what's with the dummy text ?

Comment: Input value does change on changing selectbox option , whats the problem actually

Comment: sorry, the text dummy just to pass my question because too many code.

Comment: when you run my snippet. you clone until three or more.

Comment: if you select orange, its will be change all value in `<input type='text' name='show'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following: clear the input after the cloning, at change select the show input that is relative to the select:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addBarang();
});

function addBarang() {
  var new_barang = $(".hidden_input").find(".barang_in").clone().addClass("barang_in_clone");
  $(".target_clone:last").append(new_barang);
  $(".barang_in_clone:last").find("input[name=show]").val('');
  //        $(".barang_in_clone:has(select)").addClass("select2");
}

$('body').on('click', '.btn_kurangi_barang', function() {
  $(this).closest('.barang_in_clone').remove();
});

function showModel(el){
if(el.value === ''){
$(el).siblings("input[name=show]").val("");
}else if(el.value === "1"){
$(el).siblings("input[name=show]").val("foo");
}else if(el.value === "2"){
$(el).siblings("input[name=show]").val("bar");
}else{
$(el).siblings("input[name=show]").val("too");
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="hidden_input" style="display: none">
    <div class="barang_in">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Kode Hanca</label>
      <select onchange='showModel(this)' name="id_vendor_detail" class="form-control" required="">
        <option value="">- PILIH -</option>
        <option value="1">- Orange -</option>
        <option value="2">- Pink -</option>
        <option value="3">- Red -</option>

      </select>
      <button onclick="addBarang()" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="tambah vendor" class="btn btn-info btn-flat btn-xs pull-left btn_tambah_vendor"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add</button>
      <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="kurangi barang" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-xs pull-right btn_kurangi_barang"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove</button>
      <input type='text' name='show'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='target_clone'>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: yeah, its very helpful for beginner like me.. thanks madalin

Comment: guys, why if i combination it with ajax make browser hang ? i added ajax like it :

Comment: function showModel(el) {
        if (el === "") {
            $(el).siblings("input[name=model]").val("");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {id_vendor_detail: el, type: "get_model"}, //get model dan ukuran

Comment: success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $(el).siblings("input[name=model]").val(data.nama_model + " " + "(" + data.ukuran + ")");
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    //called when there is an error
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
        }
    }

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan post another question so we can help you with that

Comment: please visit [vist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785746/select-onchange-with-ajax) Madalin. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/9t01777r/

HTML

```
<div class="hidden_input" style="display: none">
      <div class="barang_in">
         <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Kode Hanca</label>
         <select onchange='showModel(this)' name="id_vendor_detail" class="form-control" required="">
            <option value="">- PILIH -</option>
            <option value="1">- Orange -</option>
            <option value="2">- Pink -</option>
            <option value="3">- Red -</option>

         </select>
         <button onclick="addBarang()" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="tambah vendor" class="btn btn-info btn-flat btn-xs pull-left btn_tambah_vendor"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add</button>
         <button onclick="removeBarang(this)" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="kurangi barang" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-xs pull-right btn_kurangi_barang"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove</button>
         <input type='text' name='show'>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class='target_clone'>
   </div>
```

Javascript

```
var addBarang = function() {
   var new_barang = $(".hidden_input").find(".barang_in").clone(true).addClass("barang_in_clone");
   $(".target_clone").append(new_barang);
   //          $(".barang_in_clone:has(select)").addClass("select2");
}
var showModel = function(obj) {
   var id = $(obj).val();
   if (id === '') {
      $(obj).closest('.barang_in').find('input[name=show]').val("");
   } else if (id === "1") {
      $(obj).closest('.barang_in').find('input[name=show]').val("foo");
   } else if (id === "2") {
      $(obj).closest('.barang_in').find('input[name=show]').val("bar");
   } else {
      $(obj).closest('.barang_in').find('input[name=show]').val("too");
   }
}

var removeBarang = function(ths) {
   $(ths).closest('.barang_in_clone').remove();
}
$(function() {
   addBarang();
});
```