# Select Onchange with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, select, clone

i have problem with change by ajax. this is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addBarang();
});

function addBarang() {
  var new_barang = $(".hidden_input").find(".barang_in").clone().addClass("barang_in_clone");
  $(".target_clone:last").append(new_barang);
  $(".barang_in_clone:last").find("input[name=show]").val('');
  //        $(".barang_in_clone:has(select)").addClass("select2");
}

$('body').on('click', '.btn_kurangi_barang', function() {
  $(this).closest('.barang_in_clone').remove();
});

 //Tampilkan model ketika memilih kode hanca
    function showModel(el) {
        if (el === "") {
            $(el).siblings("input[name=model]").val("");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {id_vendor_detail: el, type: "get_model"}, //get model dan ukuran
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $(el).siblings("input[name=model]").val(data.nama_model + " " + "(" + data.ukuran + ")");
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    //called when there is an error
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="hidden_input" style="display: none">
    <div class="barang_in">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Kode Hanca</label>
      <select onchange='showModel(this)' name="id_vendor_detail" class="form-control" required="">
        <option value="">- PILIH -</option>
        <option value="1">- Orange -</option>
        <option value="2">- Pink -</option>
        <option value="3">- Red -</option>

      </select>
      <button onclick="addBarang()" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="tambah vendor" class="btn btn-info btn-flat btn-xs pull-left btn_tambah_vendor"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add</button>
      <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="kurangi barang" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-xs pull-right btn_kurangi_barang"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove</button>
      <input type='text' name='show'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='target_clone'>
  </div>

</body>
```

when i select the selectbox, it make my browser hang . how to fix it ?

//this is dummy text for pass the question because mostly code : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at lectus orci. Quisque maximus hendrerit consequat. Donec blandit facilisis est. Integer ac massa vitae ante vulputate sagittis nec at nisl. Cras sit amet sem nec metus sodales eleifend a ac nulla. Duis porta nisl in erat aliquet hendrerit. Integer mollis non odio et pellentesque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse cursus fringilla sem, facilisis malesuada orci varius in. Nullam tristique nisi sed sem mattis, a finibus magna mollis. Fusce erat sem, semper ac vulputate sit amet, imperdiet sagittis ex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`el` is the element not the value of the element

use `el.value` to get the selected value or `$(el).val();` via jquery

```
  function showModel(el) {
        if (el.value === "") {
            $(el).siblings("input[name=model]").val("");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {id_vendor_detail: el.value, type: "get_model"}, //get model dan ukuran
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $(el).closest('.barang_in').find("input[name='model']").val(data.nama_model + " " + "(" + data.ukuran + ")");//get the parent element and then find the input
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    //called when there is an error
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by browser hangs?

Comment: at now, the browser not hangs. i change `id_vendor_detail: el.value` with `id_vendor_detail: el` and return json is ok. but, the value in `$(el).siblings("input[name=model]").val(data.nama_model + " " + "(" + data.ukuran + ")");` not fill by value that return from json

Comment: @wawanSetiyawan i don't see no sibling input with the name model in your html code

Comment: oh, i forget it to change. but in my real html set the name is `model` , not `show` like snippet above. it same Madalin. the `$(el).siblings("input[name=model]").val(data.nama_model + " " + "(" + data.ukuran + ")");` not show the data

Comment: can you drop a sample of the response json you receive

Comment: but, when i change `$(el).siblings("input[name=model]").val(data.nama_model + " " + "(" + data.ukuran + ")");` with `$("input[name=model]").val(data.nama_model + " " + "(" + data.ukuran + ")");` . it show the data in value, but all `<input type='text' name='model'>` be set by data that same. :(

Comment: i think that is right, but it still same. it can't find the element ` $(el).closest('.barang_in').find("input[name=model]").val(data.nama_model + " " + "(" + data.ukuran + ")");`, maybe..

Comment: are you 100% sure the element is named model ?

Comment: yes Madalin. because, when i change to `$("input[name=model]").val(da‌​ta.nama_model + " " + "(" + data.ukuran + ")");` . it okay and show data, but all the data is same

Comment: yosh, i change `showModel(this.value)` to `showModel(this)` and `data: {id_vendor_detail: el, type: "get_model"}, ` to `data: {id_vendor_detail: el.value, type: "get_model"},` before i change it, it make my browser hangs.

Comment: thanks Madalin. it very helpful. thanks so much .. :)